# How can i fix searchcontroller animate ui screen when add to naviationitem to searchbar in ios 11?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

[image]

How can I fix the search controller animate UI screen when adding to navigation item to the search bar in IOS 11?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it for iPhone X and its working fine. Make sure your navigation controller isn't nil in viewcontroller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var searchController: UISearchController!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
//    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  }

  func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  }

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    search(sender: searchBar)
  }
}
```